# How to get data from the server through an interval?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I use angular6, i try get json from server through 5 seconds interval.

[JSFIDDLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lsqhfq)

Its my service:

```
getExample(): Observable<any> {
    console.log('getExample');
    return Observable
      .timer(0, 5000)
      .flatMap(() => this.httpClient.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts'))
      .map((r) => {
        return r;
      });
  }
```

Please help fix this code.

PS: more simple service [worked](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q5ykue) without problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RxJS 6 has updated to use [pipeable operators](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md). Also, timer [imports from a different path](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#import-paths). You should import `timer` (or `interval` in this case) directly and use `.pipe` with the operators that you need. Finally, use `mergeMap` instead of `flatMap`.

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

return interval(5000).pipe(
  mergeMap(() => this.httpClient.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')),
  map((r) => {
    console.log(r);
    return r;
  })
);
```